# Transactional logs and how best to run action per line

Tags: python, bash, logging, sip

Ok so I have a small project whereby when my SIP phones goes I want some lights to flash on my desk or go green red or yellow depending on my status.

How I am doing this is just a simple command line then dumping out to a log.

```
sudo tcpdump | sed '/200 OK/d' | grep --color 'Ringing\|BYE\|Terminated\|CANCEL\|ACK sip:171@194.213.29.63:5061 SIP/2.0\|'
```

Log files:

```
01:05:37.689480 IP 194.*.sip > 192.168.0.2.54508: SIP: SIP/2.0 180
01:05:39.088431 IP 192.168.0.2.56096 > 194.213.29.63.14248: UDP, length 172
....... While on phone lots of UDP packets...... 
01:05:39.088431 IP 192.168.0.2.56096 > 194.213.29.63.14248: UDP, length 172
01:05:42.608911 IP 192.168.0.2.54508 > 194.*.sip: SIP: BYE sip:171@194.213.29.63:5061 SIP/2.0
```

Processes:

```
CALL COMMING IN (flash lights)
ON THE PHONE: (Turn lights red) 
CALL FINISHED: (Turn lights green)
```

Wondering if anyone has best Idea on how to do the following I have hardware working just need to send it signal. Its more the parsing on this log file and how best to do this.

Do I need it so that if one thing happens then another things should happen and just be based on very much reading the log file or can I do it some other way.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SIP but I found a guide showing a better way to analyze the SIP transaction packets [here](http://nil.uniza.sk/network-security/analyzers/using-tcpdump-sip-diagnostic)

Comment: Its the parsing of it that I am having issues doing. Content coming out of tcpdump is working quite well. Your right if I do sudo tcpdump dst 1.2.3.4  || src 1.2.3.4 port 5060 then I get results quicker.

Comment: If you'll be kind enough to post an example output with some anchors I can work with, the output you posted doesn't contain anything I can filter out 

(01:05:37.689480 IP 194.*.sip > 192.168.0.2.54508: SIP: SIP/2.0 180, is this an incoming call?)